# Table-specific storage engines blocking mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql, storage-engine

I've just installed MySQL 8.0 on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.  I tried running `mysql_secure_installation`, but I got the following error:

```
New password:    
  
Re-enter new password:    
... Failed! Error: Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables.  
[mysql.db]
```

This [Digital Ocean post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04) explains that the error is related to the MySQL root user's default authentication plugin in the Ubuntu package, and offers steps to correct the problem by changing root's plugin.  When I try this method, however, I get the same error within the MySQL interactive prompt:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '***';  
ERROR 1726 (HY000): Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db]
```

If I restart the MySQL service and check the journal using `$ sudo journalctl -u mysql | less`, I find the following lines referring to the MySQL standard tables `mysql.db` and `mysql.columns_priv`:

```
Sep 04 08:35:47 System mysqld[639418]: 2022-09-02T12:35:47.209099Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db].
Sep 04 08:35:47 System mysqld[639418]: 2022-09-02T12:35:47.209118Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.columns_priv].
```

The reference to `MyISAM` in these errors strikes me as particularly odd, since I understood `MyISAM` hasn't been the default storage engine for MySQL in over a decade.  If I check the engines of the various tables in the `mysql` database, however, I find several that are `MyISAM`, including `mysql.db` and `mysql.columns_priv`:

```sql
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME,ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql';
+------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| TABLE_NAME                                           | ENGINE |
+------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| columns_priv                                         | MyISAM |
| component                                            | InnoDB |
| db                                                   | MyISAM |
| default_roles                                        | InnoDB |
| engine_cost                                          | InnoDB |
| event                                                | MyISAM |
| func                                                 | MyISAM |
| ...                                                  | ...    |
```

This seems to be what's ultimately blocking me from running `mysql_secure_installation`.  Are these tables supposed to be `MyISAM`?  Can I safely convert them to `InnoDB`, and should I?  What's the resolution here?  How do I complete `mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: Did you have a previous 5.7 version before installing MySQL 8 ? It never happened to me on a fresh MySQL 8 install, because the default storage engine is InnoDB.  It seems that you are trying to run 8.0 over 5.7

Comment: No, this is a fresh install of MySQL 8.  No other MySQL has ever been installed on the system.  My `$HOME` folder was carried over from a system that had MySQL 5 on it, but I've investigated and haven't found any traces of configuration there that would affect this.  All MySQL config is contained in `/etc/`, which is original to this Ubuntu 22.04 system.

Comment: @ErgestBasha If you have a fresh MySQL 8 installation available, would you mind running the `SELECT TABLE_NAME,ENGINE ...` command in my post and let me know if any tables in `mysql`, particularly `mysql.db` and `mysql.columns_priv` have the `MyISAM` engine?  I would appreciate the comparison.

Comment: I did run it before my first comments and the storage engine is InnoDB as it should be. Your problem I think is here *My $HOME folder was carried over from a system that had MySQL 5*. Perform a cleanup and a fresh install and do not use an older home directory . the result of `SELECT TABLE_NAME,ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mysql';` in my 8.0.29 version https://dbfiddle.uk/YYiK9MPN

Comment: Unless we can identify the file in `$HOME` that's at fault, I have a hard time believing that's the issue.  In any event, I'm not going to throw away my entire home folder on a guess :).  Instead, I'm going to attempt to manually change those tables to `InnoDB` and see what happens; I'll post the results.  Thanks for checking your installation, it's a big help.  I think that might be the wrong fiddle you posted, though?

Comment: If you manually change the tables engine , probably they will be corrupted , be very careful with that. Check  https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98733 first .